# Add GitLab CI job to pipeline based on script command result

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a GitLab CI pipeline with a 'migration' **job which I want to be added only if certain files changed** between current commit and `master` branch, but in my current project I'm forced to use GitLab CI pipelines for `push` event which complicates things.

[Docs on rules:changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges) clearly states that it will glitch and will not work properly without MR (my case of `push` event), so that's out of question.

[Docs on rules:if](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif) states that it only works with env variables. But [docs on passing CI/CD variables to another job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job) clearly states that

> These variables cannot be used as CI/CD variables to configure a
> pipeline, but they can be used in job scripts.

So, now I'm stuck. I can just **skip running the job** in question overriding the `script` and checking for file changes, but what I want is **not adding the job in question to pipeline** in first place.

Answer (score 3):

While you can't add a *job* alone to a pipeline based on the output of a script, you can add a child pipeline dynamically based on the script output. The method of using `rules:` with dynamic variables won't work because `rules:` are evaluated at the time the pipeline is created, as you found in the docs.

However, you can achieve the same effect using [dynamic child-pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/parent_child_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines) feature. The idea is you dynamically create the YAML for the desired pipeline in a job. That YAML created by your job will be used to create a *child* pipeline, which your pipeline can depend on.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, to add/remove a Gitlab job based on variables created from a previous job is not possible for a `given` pipeline

A way to achieve this is if your break your current pipeline to an upstream and downstream

The upstream will have 2 jobs

1. The first one will use your script to define a variable
2. This job will trigger the downstream, passing this variable

Upstream

```
check_val:
 ...
 script:
   ... Script imposes the logic with the needed checks
   ... If true
   - echo "MY_CONDITIONAL_VAR=true" >> var.env
   ... If false 
   - echo "MY_CONDITIONAL_VAR=false" >> var.env
 artifacts:
  reports:
    dotenv: var.env

trigger_your_original_pipeline:
    ...
    variables:
      MY_CONDITIONAL_VAR: "$MY_CONDITIONAL_VAR"
    trigger:
        project: "project_namespance/project"
```

The downstream would be your original pipeline

Downstream

```
... 
migration:
...
  rules:
   - if: '$MY_CONDITIONAL_VAR == "true"'
```

Now the `MY_CONDITIONAL_VAR` will be available at the start of the pipeline, so you can impose rules to add or not the `migration` job